# Activation of network connection failed - newbie

Tags: networking, internet, wired

I dual booted ubuntu yesterday and it was working fine.
Today I used express vpn for a while and when I disconnected the internet won't connect anymore.
Tried reinstalling the network manager which I saw  in some solutions but now it says "Activation of network connection failed" when I try to connect.
I don't know what is going on, please help.

Thanks.

I saw many guides about it but being a newbie idk how to do most of these things and idk even if those are the solution.

Edit 1 -
So I went out and shut the computer down for a few hours. came back and logged into windows and then eventually ubuntu, and the network conncted automatically. I don't get it I rebooted a few times before it didn't fix it but now it got fixed automatically.
I am going to try and connect with vpn and disconnect again to check if the error happens again.

[network manager status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk0tt.jpg)

Comment: Internet how? Cabled, wifi, usb dongle?

Comment: It' wired. Sorry I failed to mention that.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `nmcli` then get back to us.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VdppGxh - this is what I get after nmcli.

Comment: Try `nm-connection-editor` which is just a different gui. It might allow you to connect.